# Find the biggest sentence in a txt file using Python

Tags: python, file, while-loop, max

I'm trying to find the biggest sentence in a text file. I'm using the dot (.) to define the beginning and end of sentences. The text file don't have special punctuation (like ?! etc).

My code currently only return the first letter of my text file. I'm not sure why.

```py
def recherche(source):
    "find the biggest sentence"
    fs = open(source, "r")
    while 1:
        txt = fs.readline()
        if txt == "":
            break
        else:
            grande_phrase= max(txt, key=len)
            print (grande_phrase)
    fs.close()

recherche("for92.txt")
```

Comment: Think carefully about what the line `grande_phrase= max(txt, key=len)` does. What does it compute the maximum of?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code reads *each line*, and finds the `max` of *that line*. Since a string is just a collection of characters, your expression `max(txt, key=len)` gives you the *character* in `txt` that has the maximum length. Since all characters have a length of `1`, you just get the first character of the line.

You want to create a list of *all sentences*, and then use `max` on *that* list. There seems to be no guarantee that your input file will have one sentence per line. Since you use a period to define where a sentence ends, you're going to have to [*split*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the entire file at `.` to get your list of sentences. Keep in mind that this is not a foolproof strategy to split any text into sentences, since you risk splitting at *other occurrences* of `.`, such as a decimal point or an abbreviation.

```
def recherche(source):
    "find the biggest sentence"
    with open(source, "r") as fs:
        sentences = fs.read().split(".")

    grande_phrase = max(sentences, key=len)
    print(grande_phrase)
```

With an input file that looks like so:

```
It was the best of times. It was the worst of times. It was the age of wisdom. It was the age of foolishness. It was the epoch of belief. It was the epoch of incredulity. It was the season of light. It was the season of darkness. It was the spring of hope. It was the winter of despair.
```

we get the output:

```
It was the epoch of incredulity
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dZFBasMwEEX3PsWglQ3Fm@4KPkBWXfQARbFG0hBbEjMKrk/vSg4pMU0GtHr/z/C/0pp9DO/bRnOKnIFi0wgMoJQ6ZVi0QPYIZ5QM0UKmGaWHB7JEfoW0wwoWEhPnZ8TGOJH4gHI0Yoqjr4IzToT2OaMwMprrRHk9CAS1xFAVEzmfXzCj@fLvriSm4Cr2MeExJoWMvDtRkibuS0FNY9AC4@iRy2slXnnE7qOBMspSMLfyyLnan2DZEUZUO18o@9J2/5Xr0dPn3Q3lopXbjjp3V/0UKz2jNm3XSyrBW9WrrtmVjnUw@J08a8EBZv3T/hnf4ILrMGHodmkNmduDoSx5SNFt2y8) <sup>Note: I replaced the file with an `io.StringIO` to work on tio.run</sup>